# C How to exit from while loop with esc

Tags: c, string, loops, concurrency, break

I'd like to exit from while after typing 'esc' key into console. But unfortunatley i have no clue, how to do it without re-writing whole program.At the moment it exits the loop after ctrl+D.

```
    char* getUserInput(int bytes)
    {
      char* buffer = malloc(bytes);
      char* line = malloc(bytes);
      size_t len = 0;


      while (getline(&line, &len, stdin) > 0)  //I'd like to add one while condition
    //here, that will check if esc was pressed, like &&(_getch()!=27) 
    //or &&(!strcmp(line, (char)27)

      {
        strcat(buffer, line);
        line = malloc(bytes);
      }

      buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';
      return buffer;
    }
```

Comment: No problem: `if(line[0] == 27) break;`

Comment: That Was too easy -.- i feel like a moron now. Thank You :D

Comment: I learned it for the first time once too!

Comment: @Beta better to do `if (line[0] == '\e')` to not depends on the code number

Comment: @bruno: Good point.

Comment: OT, but still wrong:  1. Memory referred to by `buffer` is not initialized, but you `strcat` to it - that's undefined behavior.  2. You never free `line`.  3.  `buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';` will truncate the last character from `line` if it doesn't end with `'\n'`.  `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;` is much better. 4. `bytes` should be `unsigned int` else a negative value passed in will likely cause `malloc` to fail.  5. You don't check for `malloc` failure.

Answer (score 2):

See the code bellow. Hope it will help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    do{
        ch = getch();
        printf("Inputed char: %c\n", ch);
    }while(ch != 27);
}
```